# According to what I know you cannot echo an array. You have to loop through it. Why are the values of my array printed?

Tags: php

I have this data:

```
1CPT5

'stock' => array (
  'warehouse' => 
  array (
    'warehouse_id' => 1,
    'name' => 'CPT',
  ),
  'quantity_available' => 5,
)

3JHB21

'stock' = > array (
  'warehouse' => 
  array (
    'warehouse_id' => 3,
    'name' => 'JHB',
  ),
  'quantity_available' => 21,
)
```

and this code that is looping through the above data.

```
    foreach ($row['stock'] as $val) {
        foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $warehouse => $name) {
            echo $name;
        }
        echo $val['quantity_available'];
        echo '<pre>' . var_export($val, true) . '</pre>';
    }
```

I am trying to display the quantity_available based on the ID of the warehouse (there are 2 warehouses) The first set of data is for warehouse_id 1 with name CPT and number of items 5.
The second set of data is for warehouse_id 3 with name JHB and number of items 21.
'warehouse' is an array and according to what I know you can only loop through an array, print_r or var_dump an array. Why if I then echo $name do I see all the values of the array and how do I isolate them so I can just get the id and based on the id display the quantity associated with that id?

I finally figured it out and the following code displays the number I am after:

```
    foreach ($row['stock_at_takealot'] as $key => $val) {

        foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 1) {
                echo $val['quantity_available'];
            }
        }
    };
```

but now I have another issue where all the values are displayed in one cell instead of two. What is my mistake here please?

```
    <td class='small centerCol'>";
    foreach ($row['stock_at_takealot'] as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 1) {
                echo $val['quantity_available'];
            }
        }
    };
    "</td>
    <td class='small centerCol'>";
    foreach ($row['stock_at_takealot'] as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 3) {
                echo $val['quantity_available'];
            }
        }
    };
    "</td>
    <td class='small centerCol'>"
```

Comment: `echo $val['warehouse']['warehouse_id']`

Comment: Hi. You can directly access the values ​​of your array. You don't need to loop over a single element. ie https://onlinephp.io/c/005a5

Comment: You're looping an associative array: `array ('warehouse_id' => 1, 'name' => 'CPT',)` For each key => value pair, you'd get the key=>value pair sent into $warehouse=>$name. And you're echoing $name without also echoing the key. If you're interested in specific keys in the associative array, access them by key name rather than trying to loop them with your inner loop.

Comment: I figured it out but now have another issue so I edited my question. Thank you all your guidance is helping me learn so much.

Comment: Why keep looping over result? Can you give us a var_export($row['stock_at_takealot']) please?

Comment: You can do otherwise, but you can also continue as you are doing and browse your table to test on each td https://onlinephp.io/c/d8ae2